# Which version should I install node, react-native, expo, firebase, etc. so that there are no dependency problems?

Tags: firebase, react-native, npm, expo, version

I am beginning developer.

1. How can I solve the dependency versioning problem?
2. Is there any information which version can be adjusted with node version?

Thank you in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use all the latest versions, so you don't get any errors.

1. **Node**: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. **react-native & Expo:**
   https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
3. **react-navigation**:
   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/
4. **firebase**: https://rnfirebase.io/

Hope it will help you!